# How to copy JObject into strongly-typed object?

Tags: c#, dynamic, json.net

for simplicity I made very simple structures.

Incoming JSON:

```
jsonInput = "{ 'FNAME': 'John'; 'LNAME': 'Doe', 'CITY': 'Vancuver'}";
```

I need to integrate with my strongly typed object of class Person:

```
class Person
{
    public string FNAME { get; set; }
    public string LNAME { get; set; }
    public string CITY { get; set; }
    public string COUNTRY { get; set; }
}
```

Person object gets created first 
(in real life from DB, but here I will just hard-code it):

```
var person = new Person { CITY = 'Toronto', COUNTRY = 'Canada'};
```

How to integrate (merge) **jsonInput** into **person** to have complete Person object. JSON data is supposed to **override Person object only for matched properties**

So, I de-serialize JSON **jsonInput** first into dynamic object

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonInput);
```

So, now I have partially populated **obj** object (that is of type **JObject**) and partially populated **person** object (of type **Person**).

How, in a single command I can merge them into **person** object.
Or maybe there is another way to deserialize **jsonInput** directly into **person** ??

The result should be:

```
person.FNAME = 'John'
person.LNAME = 'Doe'
person.CITY = 'Vancuver'
person.COUNTRY = 'CANADA'
```

What I want to avoid is looping through properties. 
Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Have you tried using `JsonConvert.PopulateObject(jsonInput, person)`? (As an aside, I'd strongly urge you to use more conventional property names. You can use attributes to express how they're mapped to JSON.)

Comment: Jon, yes I know, not my decision for property names :-)

Answer (score 3):

Use [PopulateObject](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_PopulateObject_1.htm) Method

```
JsonConvert.PopulateObject(jsonInput,person);
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming you recive json as a parameter ...

```
jsonInput = "{ 
              'PERSON' : {
                         'FNAME': 'John'; 
                         'LNAME': 'Doe', 
                         'CITY': 'Vancuver'
                        } 
             }";
Public class Person{
     public Person(string json,string city,string country){
            JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(json);
            JToken jPerson = jObject["PERSON"];
            FNAME= (string) jPerson ["FNAME"];
            LNAME= (string) jPerson ["LNAME"];

            COUNTRY = country:
            CITY= ((string) jPerson ["CITY"] == string.Empty)?city:(string) jPerson ["CITY"]; //IF CITY PROPERTY EMPTY USE CITY ELSE USE JSON PROPERTY

         }  
           public string FNAME{ get; set; }
           public string LNAME{ get; set; }
           public string CITY{ get; set; }
           public string COUNTRY{ get; set; }         
}
```

not tested but hope that helps